# Android Impossibile fill Layout height with custom view

Tags: android, view

I created a custom View, and I put this on a LinearLayout.

Problem is that I cannot fill completely the height of the layout, the size of the custom View is always squared, width = height.

Here is my layout:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight="0">

    <it.inav.graphics.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

The only way it seems to work is using a RelativeLayout and "strecth" the view using both

```
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

but still, if I try to get the size height, it returns the same length of before.

Comment: use 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
despite Using
android:layout_height="match_parent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the definition of the View, and not in the XML.

I have done copy-paste of this piece of code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int measuredWidth = measure(widthMeasureSpec);
        int measuredHeight = measure(heightMeasureSpec);
        int d = Math.min(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
        setMeasuredDimension(d, d);
    }
```

And, naturally, it sets the size of the View as a square with the length of the minor.

This is the correct code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int measuredWidth = measure(widthMeasureSpec);
        int measuredHeight = measure(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    }
```